# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I'm executing the following:

```
private void createTable() {
    try {       
        PreparedStatement psCreateTable = con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE     COMPANIES(" +
                "name VARCHAR(50), " +
                "location VARCHAR(50), " +
                "address VARCHAR(50), " +
                "website VARCHAR(50), " +
                "pit VARCHAR(50), " +
                "asset_class VARCHAR(50), " +
                "telephone INTEGER, " +
                "shares INTEGER, " +
                "value DOUBLE(,2) UNSIGNED)");
        psCreateTable.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("already exists");
        e.printStackTrace();
        ; //bestaat al
    }
}
```

And I get the following error: 
    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 195.

Not really sure what to do now, as the SQL query seems valid to me and rechecked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `(,2)` in the double data type.

```
CREATE Table Companies
(
    ....,
    value DOUBLE UNSIGNED
)
```

[See Demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/723e1/1)

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but now I get the following error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "UNSIGNED" at line 1, column 196.

Comment: Removed the 'UNSIGNED' parameter, seems to work, but now I get the following error: java.sql.SQLException: At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized.

Comment: @MarvinEffing but it's working on sql fiddle. did you  click the link?

Comment: @MarvinEffing the code you posted above is the one you are using? why is hat it shows error message `At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized.`? do you have a parameterized query othjer than that?

Comment: just clicked the link, it does indeed seem to work on sql fiddle, but i still get the same error. I'm inserting the following values as an example via a form: marvin, marvin, marvin, marvin, marvin, marvin, 1, 1, 1

Comment: can i see your insert statement?

Comment: `"INSERT INTO COMPANIES VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";`

Comment: Ok, removed one `?`, that was not very smart of me... But I still get the same error. Thought that'd fix'd it but no. :(

Comment: Yeah ok works now, I always end up forgetting the tiniest things.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query has an error: `"value DOUBLE(,2) UNSIGNED)");`

Change your PreparedStatement to something like this:

```
PreparedStatement psCreateTable = con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE COMPANIES(" +
                "name VARCHAR(50), " +
                "location VARCHAR(50), " +
                "address VARCHAR(50), " +
                "website VARCHAR(50), " +
                "pit VARCHAR(50), " +
                "asset_class VARCHAR(50), " +
                "telephone INTEGER, " +
                "shares INTEGER, " +
                "value DOUBLE UNSIGNED)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DOUBLE(,2)
```

This is wrong.

You may try

```
DOUBLE(5,2)
```